# How to stop the cmd window from closing

Tags: c#, wpf, cmd

I run PsExec in a WPF application, but after execution, the window closes.

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\SysWoW64\PsExec64.exe";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format(@"\\{0} ipconfig", TextBox_PCin.Text);
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
```

I also tried:

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\SysWoW64\PsExec64.exe";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format(@" \K \\{0} ipconfig", TextBox_PCin.Text);
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
```

but nothing happens here. A window appears only for a second.
How can I stop the window from closing? Why doesn't "WaitForExit" do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running:

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format(@"/k C:\Windows\SysWoW64\PsExec64.exe \\{0} ipconfig", TextBox_PCin.Text);
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
```

WaitForExit did not work for you because PsExec64.exe does not wait for user input at all. It take commands as an argument >> parse & run it >> exit process. So technically your "code" did wait for PsExec64.exe to exit and then continued.